# Ignoring the newline character while splitting the multiline string

Tags: python, string

I have a string like below

```
s = '''printf("\nFloat value is %f \n", flt);
printf("Integer value is %d\n" , no);
printf("Double value is %lf \n", dbl);
printf("\nOctal value is %o \n", no);
printf("Hexadecimal value is %x \n", no);
return 0;'''
```

I want to split the string. I used `splitlines()` But it's not giving the output I'm expected.
It also splitting the string if it contain `\n` in middle of the string. What i want is I want to ignore the newline characters in middle of the strings while splitting the string. Is there any way can I solve this without using the files.

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    #line = somfunction(line)
    print(line)
```

**Output of above code**

```
printf("
Float value is %f 
", flt);
printf("Integer value is %d
" , no);
printf("Double value is %lf 
", dbl);
printf("
Octal value is %o 
", no);
printf("Hexadecimal value is %x 
", no);
return 0;
```

**Expected Output:**

```
printf("\nFloat value is %f \n", flt);
printf("Integer value is %d\n" , no);
printf("Double value is %lf \n", dbl);
printf("\nOctal value is %o \n", no);
printf("Hexadecimal value is %x \n", no);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using a string raw notation in your `s` definition.

```
s = r'''printf("\nFloat value is %f \n", flt);
printf("Integer value is %d\n" , no);
printf("Double value is %lf \n", dbl);
printf("\nOctal value is %o \n", no);
printf("Hexadecimal value is %x \n", no);
return 0;'''
```

Notice the `r` in leading of string. In python this mean a string raw.

Here [is the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
s = r'''printf("\nFloat value is %f \n", flt);
printf("Integer value is %d\n" , no);
printf("Double value is %lf \n", dbl);
printf("\nOctal value is %o \n", no);
printf("Hexadecimal value is %x \n", no);
return 0;'''

for line in s.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Comment: this is not the string i posted it contain `\n` not `\\n`