# Differentiate newlines in dart string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```dart
const myString = """
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//xyz Corp//NONSGML PDA Calendar Version 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:19960704T120000Z
UID:uid1@example.com
ORGANIZER:mailto:jsmith@example.com
DTSTART:19960918T143000Z
DTEND:19960920T220000Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CATEGORIES:CONFERENCE
SUMMARY:Networld+Interop Conference
DESCRIPTION:Networld+Interop Conference and Exhibit\n Atlanta World Atlanta, Georgia
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
""";
```

Note the `\n` in the `DESCRIPTION` property.
Now I want to split the string into lines. When using `myString.split("\n")`,
it also splits the description line.
How can i tell dart to only split the "real" linebreaks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring the newline character while splitting the multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097454/ignoring-the-newline-character-while-splitting-the-multiline-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `myString` as a [raw string](https://dart.dev/language/built-in-types#strings) by adding an `r` before the opening quotes.

```dart
const myString = r"""
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//xyz Corp//NONSGML PDA Calendar Version 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:19960704T120000Z
UID:uid1@example.com
ORGANIZER:mailto:jsmith@example.com
DTSTART:19960918T143000Z
DTEND:19960920T220000Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CATEGORIES:CONFERENCE
SUMMARY:Networld+Interop Conference
DESCRIPTION:Networld+Interop Conference and Exhibit\n Atlanta World Atlanta, Georgia
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
""";

void main() {
  myString.split("\n").forEach(print);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//xyz Corp//NONSGML PDA Calendar Version 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:19960704T120000Z
UID:uid1@example.com
ORGANIZER:mailto:jsmith@example.com
DTSTART:19960918T143000Z
DTEND:19960920T220000Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CATEGORIES:CONFERENCE
SUMMARY:Networld+Interop Conference
DESCRIPTION:Networld+Interop Conference and Exhibit\n Atlanta World Atlanta, Georgia
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```